# view data from html form before submitting

Tags: php, mysql, html

i am really stuck here i have been trying and i am posting here hope some one will help me.
i have a html form where i enter my data and before submitting i need to view my data in the html form and if i need changes change it rt there and submit .
i am able to enter data and how do i display the data without submitting.

Comment: when you say "need to view my data" are you trying to validate the input data?  Or are you talking about a WYSIWYG input?

Comment: There's likely to be many ways of "previewing" data, either by posting the data to a preview page or using Javascript to open a preview container on top of the form... etc. It would be useful if you can describe how you want it to behave.

Answer (score 1):

To preview your form data before posting you have two options basically: the first is to **preview it by using JavaScript** to dynamically open a new window and then show your data formatted as you want, the second is to **post your data to your server and return a new page** containing the data you posted but not yet being integrate to your database, this is a kind of confirmation page, whatever is the option there should be a confirmation button to accept or reject the submission and integration of the data in your database.

The second option requires you to create a new page on the server side for confirmation (preview), having all the power of your web server language.

Comment: Alternatively you can also use jQuery to show preview of the formatted input somewhere next to the form as it gets entered to the form. Very much like here on stackoverflow. There is an actual plugin for this type of action already written.

Comment: @Cyber-Guard Design: yes, or some JavaScript Framework for RIA development such as ExtJS. http://www.sencha.com/products/js/.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you have a Preview button and a Save (or Post) one.
The Preview button submits the data which is processed by the server-side script (interpreting markup language, or filtering HTML or other stuff) and converted to HTML, then sent back to the user along with the text field with the raw data.
Then the Save/Post button does the same, but saves the data to the database, and similarly output the HTML, without the text field.
A quite generic answer to a quite generic question...

Answer (score 0):

The question that comes to my mind is how this preview would look different from the data entry page. I mean, if the user is supposed to enter, say, name, address, and favorite color, presumably that data is visible on the screen as they type it. What would a preview do? If you're talking about some sort of validation, like color must be on your list of approved colors or some such, then you have two basic choices: You could do the vaildation with JavaScript before sending to the server, or you could send to the server and let it do validation. I would point out that if you do client-side validation, you really should still validate on the server, esecially if there are security or hacking issues. You have no assurance that the data stream sent to your server really came from the page that you sent to the user. The user could create his own page to send data to your server.

The only other thing I can think of is a formatting preview, like here on Stack Overflow where what you type in may include codes that control format. In that case you might want to use Javascript to give immediate feedback, again, like is done here.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can have two buttons one as a preview and one as submit so when u preview it sends the form value in a different page and displays it in a format you want.

The submit button will just do the submitting etc. what u plan to do . 
hope that helps